# How to separate Header, Footer and Trailer of a FlatFile in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Suppose i have a flatFile having data like

HEADER 2082021
Rec1
Rec2
Rec3
.
.
.
Trailer total_rec_count
Footer

How to separate Header, Footer and Trailer from flatfile and load data into DB

Answer (score 1):

Two options -

1. using shell script to preprocess the data and load using three separate SQ.
2. Use informatica to sequence all rows and then separate them using the sequence number.

Each options have their pros, cons, and complexity.

Option 1 -
a. Use a shell script to generate three files - header, trailer and main file.

```
head -1 file.txt>header.txt
tail -1 file.txt>trailer.txt
sed '1d;$d' file.txt
```

b. use three separate source qualifier to process  header, trailer and file.txt.
If you have multiple files, you need to create create separate set of files and list files. And this fits nicely for multiple files because you can control them using shell script.

Option 2 -
a. Read data using one SQ with all possible fields.
b. Link a sequence generator to give unique id to each row. always start from 0 and reset every time before running.
c. Use am aggregator to get max sequence number. Pass sequence field + any dummy column and set no group by. join agg back to main pipeline using a dummy port.
d. use a router. set groups like this -

```
Seq No. = 1, then header row
Seq No. = max_row> seq >1), then main data row
Seq No. = max_row, then trailer row
```

e. Then you have three pipelines for different data set - header, trailer, and main data. Process next as per your business logic. Mapping should look like this -

```
      SQ_GEN-|        |->AGG_MAX->|                       |seq=1 header
SQ ----------|->SRT ->|---------->JNR--> RTR_SEPERATOR -->|seq=max trailer
                                                          |max > seq >1 = main data
```

Now, if you have multiple files, you need to process one file at a time and you cant process all of them together. Also, if you have millions of rows, this may be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read each record as a string
2. In expression transformation create an output port with name REC_TYPE and use SUBSTR(record,0,6).
3. Segregate the header, trailer or detail record with REC_TYPE using router or filter transformation.

- Header record : `REC_TYPE ='HEADER'`.
- Detail record : `REC_TYPE !='HEADER' && REC_TYPE !='Traile'`.
- Trailer record: `REC_TYPE = 'Traile'`.

4. Process each group as per your requirement.